# Splitting Word document into multiple .txt files using a macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am splitting a single MS Word document into multiple using a custom delimiter. I am able to create multiple files in MS Word format, but I want to create multiple .txt files instead.

The code that I am using now is:

```
Sub SplitNotes(delim As String, strFilename As String)
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim arrNotes
    Dim I As Long
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Response As Integer

    arrNotes = Split(ActiveDocument.Range, delim)

    Response = MsgBox("This will split the document into " & 
UBound(arrNotes) + 1 & " sections. Do you wish to proceed?", 4)

    If Response = 7 Then Exit Sub

    For I = LBound(arrNotes) To UBound(arrNotes)

        If Trim(arrNotes(I)) <> "" Then

            X = X + 1

            Set doc = Documents.Add
            doc.Range = arrNotes(I)

            doc.SaveAs ThisDocument.Path & "\" & strFilename & Format(X, "000")
            doc.Close True

        End If

    Next I

End Sub


Sub test()
     '      delimiter & filename
    SplitNotes "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%", "Notes "
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: You aren't telling it a file format. `Sub SaveAs([FileName], [FileFormat], [LockComments], [Password], [AddToRecentFiles], [WritePassword], [ReadOnlyRecommended], [EmbedTrueTypeFonts], [SaveNativePictureFormat], [SaveFormsData], [SaveAsAOCELetter], [Encoding], [InsertLineBreaks], [AllowSubstitutions], [LineEnding], [AddBiDiMarks])
`

Comment: can you please fix it somehow. i am not good at coding.

Comment: i dont need multiple things. the file should be saved in .txt only. as WORD document also contains text. No special formatting though.

Comment: `[..]` means OPTIONAL parameter that all the above are. `ActiveDocument.SaveAs , wdFormatPlainText`. The comma shows I've omitted the file name but you can put it in.

Comment: If you put the text caret on `SaveAs` and press F1 you will get help explaining how to use the command. Also you can see how Word would write the command you want by recording it. Alt + T, M, R. Do your save as. Repeat keys to stop recording. Look in VBA code editor for the code Word wrote. Also pressing Ctrl + I to show parameters, Ctrl + Space to show autocomplete names while typing the function.

Comment: @ACatInLove You should perhaps post it as an answer? Your comment seems to be the solution to Shani's problem.

Comment: @jpr Not reading help that's under your nose is not a worthwhile question. If he reads help in the future my comments are worth it.

Comment: @ACatInLove Got it. I'm still trying to better understand good/standard practices on this site.

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it does what you want.

```
Sub SplitNotes(delim As String, strFilename As String)
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim arrNotes
    Dim I As Long
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Response As Integer

    arrNotes = Split(ActiveDocument.Range, delim)

    Response = MsgBox("This will split the document into " & UBound(arrNotes) + 1 & " sections. Do you wish to proceed?", 4)
    If Response = 7 Then Exit Sub
    For I = LBound(arrNotes) To UBound(arrNotes)
        If Trim(arrNotes(I)) <> "" Then
            X = X + 1
            Set doc = Documents.Add
            doc.Range = arrNotes(I)
            doc.SaveAs ThisDocument.Path & "\" & strFilename & ".txt"
            doc.Close True
        End If
    Next I
End Sub


Sub test()
     ' delimiter & filename
    SplitNotes "///", "Notes "
End Sub
```